# How to split emails which are seperated by comma(,) containing special characters in sender name?

Tags: java, email, split

I have been working on splitting emails which in turn seperated by commas. For example, consider below three emails:

```
"my@.>,"<xyz@abc.com>,mine@abc.com,"my,s"elf"<pqr@abc.com>,"myself"<lmn@abc.com>
```

The result of splitting should be like:

```
1) "my@.>,"<xyz@abc.com>
2) "my,s"elf"<pqr@abc.com>
3) "myself"<lmn@abc.com>
4) mine@abc.com
```

I have tried using split() in java but there were commas(,) in sender name which makes the splitting process tedious. Is there any way to combine those emails in java?

Note: The emails can also contain quotes( " ) in sender name as well.

Comment: your string is not in proper format

Comment: can you please why it is not in proper format. If you confuse between quotes then the quotes were escaped properly

Comment: Based on valid email address format

Comment: Also I think this is not a duplicate question as the related question involves only commas in between quotes.

Comment: Is it a real life case ? Will we have comma in person names ? If reallly happens, since it is quite strange kind of data, i think may be u can split based on `>,` or  even `.com>,` and then add `>` or `.com>` at the end of the string

Comment: Your string is a mess, are you getting it from an external program/data source or are you generating them?

Comment: Here, with this expression you should be able to get going somewhere:
https://regex101.com/r/ahHA2K/1
Of course if your data has even more irregularities in its formatting it's going to require further treatment.